# Send email with Sendgrid facility with attachment throw exception NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java

I tried to use send grid email facility to send email with attachment in Java but unfortunately the code throw exception NoHttpResponseException.

The exception msg is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: api.sendgrid.com failed to respond.

I'm using sendgrid version 4.9.3, commons-codec 1.15 and httpclient5 version 5.2.1. On top of that, I'm attached Java code for reference.

```
public synchronized void sendEmail() {
        try {
            Email from = new Email("qa-automation@revmedia.my");
            String subject = "Buletin TV3 Test Automation Report";
            Email to = new Email("nicholaswkc34@gmail.com");
            Content content = new Content("text/plain", "Dear Stakeholders, please find the test automation report from attachment");
            Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

            Path reportFilePath = Paths.get(".//report//TestReport-Spark.html");
            Attachments attachments = new Attachments();
            attachments.setFilename("TestReport-Spark.html");
            attachments.setType("text/html");
            attachments.setDisposition("attachment");

            byte[] attachBytes = Files.readAllBytes(reportFilePath);
            String attachContent = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(attachBytes);
            String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(attachBytes);
            attachments.setContent(s);
            mail.addAttachments(attachments);

            SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("API_Keys");
            Request request = new Request();

            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = sg.api(request);

            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
            System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace Info:

> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
> org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
> org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
> org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
> org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
> org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
> org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
> com.sendgrid.Client.executeApiCall(Client.java:377)
> com.sendgrid.Client.post(Client.java:249)
> com.sendgrid.Client.api(Client.java:407)
> com.sendgrid.BaseInterface.makeCall(BaseInterface.java:253)

I don't know what wrong with it. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please help me as this is my work. I need to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Please help me as this is important task to me. Im very appreciate your help.

Comment: Please helkp me on this as im having serious problem. I had encoded the attachment in base64 but still cannot send attachment in code.